# drupal 7 exposed view show or hide photo

Tags: views, forms

I have a photo field that I want to show or hide depending on if the user has selected it as a tickbox. I tried to add a condition for the photo but there doesnt seem to be an option when to hide the photo.  I had a look at the fid properties of an exposed view but I am thinking I will need to create a custom field and then write my own query for showing or hiding the image field. Please let me know if you need more information to best answer the question.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this? And looks like its been a month...so if you have solved your issue, then please edit your question with more details and post your answer too. Thanks.